# Git merge show file conflicts but that file not changed in one side branch since the common ancestor(commit)

Tags: git, git-merge, git-merge-conflict

I have two branches `version-1.0` and `version-2.0`, their common ancestor is commit `C`.

I try to merge the two branch and it shows a file `a.txt` conflicted.

for example:

```
$ git checkout version-2.0
$ git merge version-1.0
$ git status 
Unmerged paths:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." as appropriate to mark resolution)
    deleted by them: a.txt

$ git ls-files -u | grep a.txt
100644 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 1       a.txt
100644 yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy 2       a.txt

$ git --version    # The git enviroment
git version 2.34.1.windows.1
```

I get common ancestor commit `C` from this command: `git merge-base version-1.0 version-2.0`.

But `git diff --stat C version-1.0` didn't show any change of `a.txt` file.

How does Git make this file conflicted?

How to get more details when Git Merge two branch?

Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Does `git rev-parse C:a.txt version-1.0:a.txt` list the same SHA1 twice? Or do you get error `fatal: path 'a.txt' does not exist in 'version-1.0'`.

Comment: "How does Git make this file conflicted?" Well, the message from Git tells you the answer. One side edited this file, but the other side deleted the file. That's a conflict.

Comment: @matt I think OP's question is not about the conflict, but instead this: "But `git diff --stat C version-1.0` didn't show any change of a.txt file."

Comment: @TTT that is why my answer shows a `git diff` that gives the expected output.

Comment: @matt other than `--compact-summary` vs `--stat`, I can't tell if your diff command is different than what OP did.

Comment: My gut feeling is what OP did should have worked, so maybe OP didn't do *exactly* as described?

Comment: @TTT I don't necessarily believe anything I'm told, so perhaps the OP's "C" is not really the merge base, or the OP's `diff` command specifies it incorrectly. In my formulation, the diff is _certainly_ with the merge base.

Comment: @j6t it both get same result like this: `fatal: path 'a.txt' exists on disk, but not in 'version-1.0'
version-1.0:a.txt`

Comment: It maybe the bug of `git version 2.34.1.windows.1`. Because I tried the same merge in WSL(ubuntu 20.04) enviroment with `git version 2.25.1`, the result have no conflict file `a.txt`, it's correct!

Answer (score 1):

The `git status` output you provide is exactly what you may expect to see when one side of an attempted merge deletes a file but the other side edits the same file.

I'll give a toy example. We start with this situation:

```
* e9f73e4 (mybranch) deleted C
| * fb8c1ca (HEAD -> main) edited C
|/  
* c54f4a6 C
* 0e1d397 B
* 38615b3 A
```

We are on `main`. We attempt to merge `mybranch`, and we get a merge conflict, with exactly the status you provided:

```
% git switch main
% git merge mybranch
% git status
On branch main
You have unmerged paths.
  (fix conflicts and run "git commit")
  (use "git merge --abort" to abort the merge)

Unmerged paths:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." as appropriate to mark resolution)
    deleted by them: C

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

To see what happened, compare the merge-base to "them" (`mybranch`), using the `compact-summary` option to give a nice clear output:

```
% git diff --compact-summary $(git merge-base main mybranch) mybranch
 C (gone) | 1 -
 1 file changed, 1 deletion(-)
```

To resolve the conflict, either `git add` or `git rm` the affected file, and then say `git merge --continue`. Let's say I agree with "them":

```
% git rm C
rm 'C'
% git merge --continue
[main d19f36b] Merge branch 'mybranch'
```

The merge succeeds and life goes on.

Comment: But the output of `git diff --compact-summary $(git merge-base version-1.0 version-2.0) version-1.0 | grep a.txt`  is also emtpy in my situation.

Comment: @Alex: if the two hash IDs `xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx` and `yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy` differ, the contents of the two files (in merge base and HEAD commits) differ. You can view the contents directly with `git show :1:a.txt` and `git show :2:a.txt`.

Comment: It's possible (just one *possibility*, I'm not saying this is the case here) that `git merge-base` is finding *a* merge base, but there are in fact multiple merge bases, so that `git merge -s ort` or `git merge -s recursive` (these are the defaults depending on Git version) first merge the merge bases. In this case you may see a merge conflict in the merge-base version in `:1:a.txt`.